# Select a range of fields between delimitters

Tags: python, cut

**Objective:**
replace a `cut` command with `-d` and `-f` options in a bash script with a Python script.

**bash examples:**

```
$ echo the-example-text-with-delimiters | cut -d - -f 2-4
$ example-text-with


$ echo the-example-text-with-delimiters | cut -d - -f 3-5
$ text-with-delimiters
```

Regex seems to be an obvious choice but I can't seem to come up with any straightforward solution that would allow for selecting a range of fields like cut does.

Comment: *Regex seems to be an obvious choice* -> no, splitting is the obvious choice ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can still use Regex with `str.split('-')`.

Here's how:

```py
x = 'the-example-text-with-delimiters'
i,j = 2,4
cut_x  = '-'.join(x.split('-')[i-1:j])
print(cut_x)
```

The printed value would be: `'example-text-with'`

Comment: I was about to post almost the same answer, so I improved yours instead ;)

Comment: Nice approach! I was focusing on Regex but indeed, split should be used here.

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex:

`\w` - Matches any alphanumeric character (digits and alphabets)

```
import re
x = 'the-example-text-with-delimiters'
i,j = 2,4

cut_x = '-'.join(re.findall(r'\w+', x)[i-1:j])
```

Output :

```
'example-text-with'
```